# Optimizing a wordpress site that won't be updated anymore

Tags: javascript

One issue I have is that "Remove unused javascript" is taking up the most time for the website "https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights". The two largest scripts are recaptcha__en.js and jquery-ui.min.js. Is there anyway at all I can optomize these latter scripts? I know for jquery I can try to unload it and replace the script with vanilla javascript. But for recaptcha, what can I do in this area?

Do I just go through the code coverage and then delete the unused recaptcha code and then have it load locally?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some plugins like LiteSpeed Cache and WP Rocket where you could remove those Javascript files and it will also help you to optimize your site. SO you could like enter those url s and it would remove the javascript for loading. You could also use a lazyloader for it